# Mysql - How to eliminate rows with several colums repeated (not duplicated)

Tags: mysql, duplicates, rows

I need to delete with a query some rows from a table which 4 columns of all are identical. For example, in the table `people`:

```
+----+------+-----+--------+
| id | name | age | weight |
+----+------+-----+--------+
|  1 | luis |  24 |     52 |
|  2 | luis |  24 |     75 |
|  3 | luis |  24 |     64 |
|  4 | ali  |  32 |     50 |
+----+------+-----+--------+
```

I'd need to delete from the table just one person called 'luis' with age '24'. Ive found several solutions for deleting duplicates, but in this case luis 24 appears 3 times, and I just want to keep 1 in the table. One person with the same name and age.

I tried:

delete from people
where id not in ( select min(id)
                  from people
                  group by name, age
)

But this gave me back this error:

You can't specify target table 'translation' for update in FROM clause

I'm using a Mysql database

Comment: So how do you decide which of those three records you want to keep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM people
    WHERE people.id NOT IN (SELECT * 
       FROM (SELECT MIN(people.id)
           FROM people
           GROUP BY people.name, people.age) people)
```

This will delete multiple duplicates of name and age leaving the record with the lower id.

You can add other columns to the GROUP BY clause.

Regards

Comment: You can also select other criteria for record selection like: MAX(people.weight) or MIN(people.age). BTW vote the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @Nova, it would be nice if you could vote or accept the answer. :)

Comment: Ok!, I've accept hte answer but I can't vote until I had 15 points of reputation and I have just 1! Thanks again,

Comment: Accepting is OK! Even better than voting. Only the question maker can accept. Thanks